# Laravel one layout in all pages

Tags: php, laravel

How can I make one layout for all pages? For example I have:

header.blade.php file with my header.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

And in login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.header')
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
   </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

But when I open login page my header prints after login? Why ?
Like this:
    [image: Error]

Maybe exists easier way to use one header/footer for all pages? For example:

```
@extends('layouts.header')
~~somethingfile.php~~
@extends('layouts.footer')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end of the header file content insert
 @yield('content')

Then when you can write this

@extends('layouts.header')
     @section('content')
        ~somethings~
     @stop
   @extends('layouts.footer')

I think this may help you.

Answer (score 3):

You would normally create a layout file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('header')

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        @yield('footer')

    </body>
</html>
```

And every other file extends this file with `@extends('layout.layout')`, having its own contents in `@section`.

```
 @section('content')
      // content
 @endsection
```

or

```
  @section('header')
       // content
  @endsection
```

depending on the purpose, and so on.

Have a look on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)